# Send mails from one VM when postfix is on the other VM in the same server

Tags: email, virtual-machine

I have a server with only one IP with three VMs running:

- `http-proxy` - IP 10.77.77.254
- `email` - IP 10.77.77.101
- `services` - IP 10.77.77.104

On the Host I select with iptables, which port goes to which server. I have set up all email ports like 25, 143,... to the `email` VM.

Port 80 and 443 goes to the `http-proxy` that decides which domain goes to which VM. I have Php, ruby and rust scripts on both VMS running: the `services` VM and the `email` VM.

The `email` VM with `postfix` and `courier` works fine as my email server (and more). It can send and receive emails fine. Also scripts on that server like `php` can send out and receive emails there. There are also some user accounts on the `email` VM that have their email boxes there.

How do I have to set up my other `services` VM on the same host so scripts on that VM can send out emails too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In reality the answer for the `services` VM can be...it depends. If it is applications, you can point them to email:25/TCP.

If we are talking about daemons/services, you configure both in the `services` and `http-proxy` VMs:

- in exim, as smarthost `email`
- a simple `postfix` with a relayhost configured to point to the `email` host. As in, in `main.cf`:

  ```
  relayhost = email
  ```
- Or, you can configure a lightweight SMTP forwarder as `ssmtp`, that just forwards emails send by the `sendmail` compatible API.

In `ssmtp.conf` you define then:

```
hostname=FQDN  # full DNS name of your server where `ssmtp` is installed
mailhub=email  # name or IP address of your central SMTP server
```

sSMTP - Simple SMTP

> sSMTP is a simple MTA to deliver mail from a computer to a mail hub
>   (SMTP server). sSMTP is simple and lightweight, there are no daemons
>   or anything hogging up CPU; Just sSMTP. Unlike Exim4, sSMTP does not
>   receive mail, expand aliases, or manage a queue.

Comment: Do I have to edit the postfix config in the `email` VM?

Comment: Maybe you can add some more details what I have to do on the postfix side on my email VM in main.cf

Comment: sorry, I am really not firm in email constructions and am a bit lost with your hints. (Maybe because you didn't write in a clear english). I would need a point to point instruction which file I have to edit and what I have to change

Comment: regarding postfix: try "relayhost = email"

Comment: I used `ssmtp` now as solution on the `services` VM: I set `# The full hostname` to `hostname=domain-name-of-my-services-vm.de` and `mailhub=10.77.77.101` (the internal IP of my `email` VM). 

Here os my config: http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?f7fd6bb3ad220876#XiYcJNZDCKyHT9HoWO9pfwo+0wMiieHQk1kv0CdyVfw=

Comment: what about [`dma`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/dma) ? would that also work?

Comment: Any MTA will do, never used `dma` .

Comment: `ssmtp` is gone, can you add an example with `msmtp` please?

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to configure a post fix null client on the `services` machine.

This way the postfix on the `services` machine will forward mails to the postfix on the `email` machine.

## How:

1- install postfix on `services` machine :

```
$ yum install postfix
```

2- Configure `services` machine postfix to relay mails to the `email` machine, keep the brackets on if your using a domain name.

EDIT:

The use of barckets avoids MX record lookup from dns.

```
$ postconf -e "relayhost=[email.example.com]"
```

3- Let the Postfix mail server on the `services` machine listen only on the loopback interface for emails to deliver.

```
postconf -e "inet_interfaces=loopback-only"
```

4- Change the configuration of the null client so that mails originating from the 127.0.0.0/8  IPv4 network and the [::1]/128 IPv6 network are forwarded to the relay host by the local null client.

```
$ postconf -e "mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128"
```

5- Configure Postfix so all outgoing mails have their sender domain rewritten to the `email` machine domain email.example.com.

```
postconf -e "myorigin=email.example.com"
```

EDIT:

No brackets here because this is just a string that is going to replace your `services` machine sender domain name.

6- Restart the local postfix null client.

```
$ systemctl restart postfix
```

Comment: Which machine in step 3? And why are there no brackets in step 5?

Comment: @rubo77 I have added some clarifications to the points raised, this configuration is happening on your services machine postfix server.